# Turned off system drive on netbook to update Windows, now it disappeared

Tags: linux, netbook, hard-drive

I have an Asus EEE 901 Netbook. It has a 4gb "system" solid state drive (soldered to the motherboard) and an additional 32gb solid state drive as the primary slave. I have Ubuntu 11 installed on the 4gb drive, and Windows 7 installed on the 32gb drive. When I was trying to update to the latest Windows 7 service pack, it didn't like not being able to read the Ubuntu drive, and would fail the update.

To solve the problem, I went into the BIOS and turned off the 4gb drive. When I rebooted the system, it halted while POSTing saying that it couldn't detect a primary master drive. I could hit F1 to continue, and it booted to Windows 7. From there, I was able to update the service pack with no issues.

When I went back into the BIOS to turn the 4gb drive back on, much to my surprise it was nowhere to be found. It can't be seen in the BIOS anymore. When I go into Disk Management on Administrative Tools, I can "see" the 4gb drive, but it has no drive letter showing (it's blank) and my only option is to delete the partition.

How can I resolve this issue? Thanks!